# The space of direct decompositions

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request, representation-theory, grassmannian

The Grassmannian $\mathrm{Gr}(k, n) = O(n) / O(k)\times O(n-k)$ describes all $k$-dimensional subspaces of $\mathbb R^n$. The product space $S=\mathrm{Gr}(k, n)\times \mathrm{Gr}(n-k, n)$ represents pairs of subspaces $(U, V)$.

Some of these pairs form a direct sum decomposition $U\oplus V=\mathbb R^n$, forming a subspace
$$S' := \{(U, V) \in S\mid U\oplus V=\mathbb R^n \}.$$

I am quite sure that $S'$ is a known mathematical object, but I can't find any references on it. I checked N. Steenrod's *Fiber Bundles*, S. Watanabe's *Algebraic Geometry and Statistical Learning Theory*, T. tom Dieck's *Representation theory* and Googled "Grassmannian of pairs", "flag Grassmanian", "summand Grassmannian", but I haven't found anything.

Could you recommend me some references on this object?

Comment: Here is something you might try : we know how to characterize these pairs. Choosing a basis $u_1,\ldots, u_k$ for $U$ and a basis $v_1,\ldots, v_{n-k}$ for $V$, $\det(u_1,\ldots, u_k,v_1,\ldots, v_{n-k}) \ne 0$ if and only if $U+V$ is a direct sum (and hence spans all of $\Bbb{R}^n$). This function is clearly not independent of choice of basis, but its vanishing locus is. So, you might define $S'\subset S$ to be the zero locus of this function which we could informally write as $(U,V)\mapsto \det(U,V)$. I haven't tried the computation, but I bet if you write it in local coordinates...

Comment: you will find that it is a submanifold of $S$.

Comment: Indeed! :) This is also how I handle these computationally (enforcing the absolute value of the determinant to be larger than a chosen $\epsilon$ for numerical stability).
It's also possible to generate them using $GL(n)$ by writing $\mathbb R^n=\mathbb R^k \oplus \mathbb R^{n-k}$ and acting with a matrix $A=GL(n)$ (again, in practice with an $\epsilon$ constraint).

However, I believe this is an important enough object that it has been studied before and may have quite interesting theory...

Comment: Yet another possibility is to describe them using the Schubert variety and use the canonical angles between flats, but I still believe it's not the end of the story.

Comment: Isn't it just $GL(n)/(GL(k)\times GL(n-k))$?

Comment: Perhaps you could say more about why you're interested in this space and how you want to use it.

Comment: Good point, thank you! I've been working on a problem which requires optimization over decompositions (which is possible by optimizing over $GL(n)$, although it has some redundant parameters) and sampling (which is possible by rejection sampling from the product of Grassmannians using the measures inherited from the Haar measure on $O(n)$. The trick is that $S'$ is open in the product space, so we can pull back the probability measure.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in the comment by @Deane you can easily describe the space of interest as the homogeneous space $GL(n,\mathbb R)/(GL(k,\mathbb R)\times GL(n-k,\mathbb R))$. The argument for this is that $GL(n,\mathbb R)$ acts transitively on the spaces pairs of subspaces $V,W\subset\mathbb R^n$ of the right dimensions such that $\mathbb R^n=V\oplus W$ and for the "standard pair" $V=\mathbb R^k$, $W=\mathbb R^{n-k}$, the stabilizer subgroup is the subgroup $GL(k,\mathbb R)\times GL(n-k,\mathbb R)$ of block diagonal matrices.

Howewer this does not correspond to the "orthogonal" interpretation of the Grassmannian as $O(n)/(O(k)\times O(n-k))$ that you start from. Indeed that space of decompositions $\mathbb R^n=V\oplus W$ is *not* a homogeneous space of $O(n)$ (since (roughly speaking)) $O(n)$ presereves the "angle" between $V$ and $W$. The corresponding homogeneous space of $O(n)$ is the space of orthogonal decompositions $\mathbb R^n=V\oplus_{\perp} W$, but this coincides with the Grassmannian itself, since any $k$-dimensional subspace determines the decomposition $\mathbb R^n=V\oplus V^\perp$ and this is the only orthogonal decomposition with first factor $V$.

So to get the Grassmannian nicely into the picture, you should view it as $GL(n,\mathbb R)/P$, where $P$ is the subgroup $\left\{\begin{pmatrix} A & B\\ 0 & C\end{pmatrix}:A\in GL(k,\mathbb R), C\in GL(n-k,\mathbb R)\right\}$. Then you can view $H:=GL(k,\mathbb R)\times GL(n-k,\mathbb R)$ naturally as subgroup of $P$ and correspondinly, you get a projection $G/H\to G/P$ (defined by $gH\mapsto gP$) which maps a decomposition to its first summand. Indeed, this is a fiber bundle with standard fiber $P/H$ (which naturally is an affine space).